# Describing and drawing the lines in the plane from $|z+1-4i|=7$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am told to describe the lines in the plane by the equation $|z+1-4i|=7$. However, isn't this equation a circle? Specifically, "Describe and draw the lines in the plane defined by the equation...".

Do...they wish me to expand this into the complex form of a circle? There are no lines to describe unless I am mistaken

Comment: This is indeed a circle. The exercise might mean a circle is one line???

Comment: Sure, you have a circle. That's your line. A slightly curved one, may I say.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Hah. True indeed. Thank you both for the swift comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $$|z+1-4i| = 7\;,$$ Now put $z=x+iy\;,$ Then equation convert into

$$\displaystyle |x+iy+1-4i| = 7\Rightarrow \sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y-4)^2} = 7$$

So we get $$(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2 = 7^2$$

So it represent a Circle with Center is at $(-1,1)$ and Radius is $7$

Comment: I agree! I suppose we can think of the circle as just a curved line.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we have $$|z+1-4i|=7$$ $$\iff \color{blue}{|z-(-1+4i)|=7}$$ The above complex form shows that the locus of the parametric point $z(x, y)$ is a circle with center $(-1, 4)$ & a radius $7$ in the complex plane.